# "with her" vs "to her"

Tags: meaning

Will it mean the same if I say:

> I tied the knot with her.

and

> I tied the knot to
>    her.

Comment: Questions about common idioms may find warmer reception on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), which is specifically intended for use by people in the earlier stages of English learning.

Answer (score 2):

Both your examples are identical, but judging by the title, I assume you meant "I tied the knot with her" vs. "I tied the knot to her". Is that correct?

If so, they are certainly *not* identical. The first is a figurative usage, an idiom ("to tie the knot") meaning to get married. In this case, you're marrying *her*.

The second usage isn't idiomatic, but rather should be interpreted directly - you took a piece of rope or string, and tied it in a knot around *her*. While this might also be a part of the marital relations, it's not a part of the idiom.

Comment: Thank you so much!it's more clear now.And yes it was "tied the knot TO her ".

Answer (score 1):

It won't mean the same.
When you say that you tie something **to** something else, it means you are placing those two things together (tied by something).
Example:

> 1) I tied the dog **to** the post. (The dog and the post have been placed together; as in, we can see that the dog cannot move away from the post.)
>   2) I tied the boat **to** the tree.

Hence, in your context of marriage, only *with her* is applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

No, they won't mean the same thing.

> I tied the knot with her.

This means that we tied the knot together, perhaps as a collaborative effort or both being witness to the same knot-tying activity. Most importantly, it is slang for "I married her" or "We got married".

> I tied the knot to her.

This means that I used something, perhaps a rope, to tie a particular knot, on the same piece of rope, to her. It implies that she was passive in the act, so she might not have been conscious of, compliant in, or an accomplice in the knot-tying activity itself. It does not have the same slang meaning either.